# Does the Bajoran Wormhole have "Off-ramps"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, wormhole

I'm a novice Trekkie, so the answer I'm looking for may be obvious to lots of people, but I have no idea. When traveling the wormhole, does one enter at Bajor, then exit at the Idran System, or are there ways to enter and exit the wormhole at other points along the way?

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site.

Comment: Seems like more of a physics question about the nature of wormholes than it does about the bajoran wormhole specifically.

Comment: @Shufflepants the OP is explicitly asking about a fictional wormhole in a TV series, he is not mentioning real ones at all.

Comment: @Sekhemty I know, but it seems his primary misunderstanding has more to do with wormholes in general rather than something specific to this one.

Comment: Honestly it seems to me that the question is about *this particular* wormhole.

Comment: Just, in case anyone was considering asking this on [physics.SE], please don't. The wormholes of Star Trek are so far disconnected - no pun intended - from the (highly speculative) science of "real" wormholes that it would be off topic there.

Comment: I think it'd make more sense to get clarification from the OP rather than arguing back and forth about interpretation.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The wormhole is effectively "point-to-point". It connected a point in the Bajoran system (within the Denorios belt) to a point in space 4.7 lightyears from the Idran system in the Gamma Quadrant (DS9: Emissary). There is no evidence in the show that it is possible to enter from any other point.

It was possible to end up in different realities (DS9: Crossover), but this was under exceptional circumstances, and the locations in physical space were the same.

It was also possible to end up in different times (DS9: Accession) though this was through the direct intervention of the Prophets, so may or may not be a property of the Wormhole as explained by in-universe physics.

Comment: Don't forget that it's also possible to [simply disappear](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Sacrifice_of_Angels_%28episode%29#Act_Five), if the Prophets so desire.

Comment: Note that while otherwise not scientifically accurate, this is also how the concept of wormholes is [supposed to work in the real world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole) (although no one has observed one yet, so they might simply not exist): A direct connection between two otherwise distant locations in space, without the ability to exit in between. In fact, the wormhole does not even pass through the 'in between' part of space, that's what makes it a shortcut.

Comment: @jpmc26 I'm not certain as to how 'canon' this is, but I believe in one of the novels, it was shown that the Jem'Hadar fleet was not actually 'disappeared' - just time-displaced, as with the 'other Emissary' in DS9: Accession.

Comment: @CGriffin - You're thinking of Star Trek Online. There's an STO level where you take control of a more advanced DS9 (several hundred years later) and try to fend off the Jem'Hadar fleet.

Comment: This could have been critical during the active phase of the Dominion War (first several episodes of Season 6), as the fact that the exit to the wormhole was mined, which prevented more Dominion forces from getting from the Gamma Quadrant to the Alpha Quadrant. If there were alternate exits, the Dominion forces might have been able to enter the Alpha Quadrant elsewhere, changing the outcome of the war dramatically.

Comment: @Valorum Not quite... There is an STO mission related to the Dominion fleet arriving after being "delayed", but the character is not in control of the DS (Starfleet loses control, just like they were afraid of in the show), and it doesn't take place several hundred years in the future, just a few decades (2410-ish, to DS9's 2370-ish).

Comment: @T.J.L. - Ah well. I was close.